# What is, and what use cases have the dot "." in helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

im currently going through the docs of helm, and there have been at least 3 different uses for the dot (.), is there any specific definition for it? and does it have something in common with the bash use (actual folder/files)?

some cases in the documentation

This print the accesed files in the range called before?

```
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "config1.toml" "config2.toml" "config3.toml" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
    {{ $files.Get . }}
  {{- end }}
```

This tells "mychart.app" to use the files in the current folder (bash-like behaviour)

```
{{ include "mychart.app" . | indent 4 }}
```

and this, i guess it takes the values from the whole folder??? i guess this is not correct since is not working (it has been made by another employee back then and i have to fix it)

```
{{- define "read.select-annot" -}}
{{- range $key, $value := . }}
{{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In general, `.` in Helm templates has nothing to do with files or directories.

The Helm templating language uses Go's [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) system.  There are a couple of different ways a period character can appear there.

First of all, `.` can be a character in a string:

```
{{- range tuple "config1.toml" "config2.toml" "config3.toml" }}
{{/*             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
       this is a literal string "config1.toml"             */}}
...
{{- end }}
```

Secondly, `.` can be a lookup operator.  There aren't any solid examples in your question, but a typical use is looking up in values.  If your `values.yaml` file has

```
root:
  key: value
```

then you can expand

```
{{ .Values.root.key }}
```

and the `.` before `root` and `key` navigates one level down in the dictionary structure.

The third use, and possibly the one that's confusing you, is that `.` on its own is a variable.

```
{{ . }}
```

You can do field lookups on it, and you have some examples of that: `.Files` is the same as `index . "Files"`, and looks up the field "Files" on the object `.`.

You use `.` as a variable in several places:

```
{{- $files := .Files }}        {{/* Get "Files" from . */}}
{{ . }}                        {{/* Write . as a value */}}
{{ include "mychart.app" . }}  {{/* Pass . as the template parameter */}}
```

`.` is tricky in that it has somewhat contextual meaning:

- At the top level, [Helm initializes `.` to an object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) with keys `Files`, `Release`, `Values`, and `Chart`.
- In a `define`d template, `.` is the parameter to the template.  (So when you `include` or `template`, you need to pass `.` down as that parameter.)
- In a `range` loop, `.` is the current item being iterated on.
- In a `with` block, `.` is the matched item if it exists.

In particular, the interaction with `range` can be tricky.  Let's look at a simplified version of your loop:

```
# {{ . }}
{{- range tuple "config1.toml" "config2.toml" "config3.toml" }}
- {{ . }}
{{- end }}
```

Outside the `range` loop, `.` is probably the top-level Helm object.  But inside the `range` loop, `.` is the file name (each value from the `tuple` in turn).  That's where you need to save values from `.` into local variables:

```
{{/* We're about to invalidate ., so save .Files into a variable. */}}
{{- $files := .Files }}

{{- range tuple "config1.toml" "config2.toml" "config3.toml" }}
{{/* This . is the filename from the "tuple" call */}}
{{ . }}: |-
  {{/* Call .Get, from the saved $files, passing the filename .
       as the parameter */}}
  {{ $files.Get . }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Super useful! Instead of saving `.Files` into a variable, one can also use `$.Files`: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/

Comment: BTW, it was a bit tricky to find the docs for `template` so here it is ("template actions"): https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/

Comment: So, `.` means `this.`, depending on the scope, it could mean "all config files", "this config file", "this item", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the global context in the first line like this.

```
{{- $dot := . }}
```

And then access it in a other context like a `range` like this

```
{{ $dot.Values.bla }}
```