# What is the dot used on docker inspect for?

Tags: json, docker, containers

I am calling to variables of the JSON on a docker container, and I want to know what is the dot (.) for.

When you type `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' $INSTANCE_ID` you see the Mount points stored on the JSON, but the file do not mention nothing about dots.

What is the dot for? What does it mean?

Comment: In [What is, and what use cases have the dot "." in helm charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472224/what-is-and-what-use-cases-have-the-dot-in-helm-charts) I've written a very complete answer to essentially this (about a different Kubernetes-related tool also using the Go `text/template` engine) but that may be more detail than you need.

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#options):

> `--format , -f`       Format output using a custom template: ‘json’: Print in JSON format ‘TEMPLATE’: Print output using the given Go template.
> Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/formatting/ for more information
> about formatting output with templates

And:

> Docker uses Go templates which you can use to manipulate the output format of certain commands and log drivers.

So basically it's [Go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) syntax that allows you to do some string manipulations, such as:

```
docker inspect --format '{{json .Mounts}}' container
```

To format `Mounts` field as JSON.

or, this for example:

```
docker inspect --format "{{upper .Name}}" container
```

Which transforms `Name` to uppercase.

See more:

- https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/
- https://pkg.go.dev/text/template

Comment: I have read all the documentation, but I still do not know what is the dot for.
Why do I need to put a dot instead of just put mounted?

Comment: It is a syntax, as their documentation mentioned: `Execution of the template walks the structure and sets the cursor, represented by a period '.' and called "dot", to the value at the current location in the structure as execution proceeds.` so basically the dot is a cursor, you have it in the beginning means that `Mount` key is on your top level

Comment: It is not like JavaScript's deconstructuring, it's just a different syntax