# Difference between $.Values and .Values in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I understand the usage of `.Values.varName` in Helm chart and which is used to refer the variable from `Values.yaml` file

I would like to know the difference between `$.Values.varName` and `.Values.varName`

For example, when I set `name: $.Values.varName` and `name: .Values.varName`

Answer (score 9):

In the Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language, like many others, `.` is a field-access operator.  In the more obvious latter half of that expression, `.Values.varName` looks up the `varName` field (either an object field or a map member) in the values object.

Helm has a standard [top-level object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) with several fields, including `Values`.  So both of these expressions normally start from the top-level object, look up `Values` in it, and then look up `varName` within that.

In the `text/template` language, `.` is *also* a variable.  When you evaluate a top-level `templates/*.yaml` file, `.` is the top-level Helm object, but inside a `define` function it's the single parameter to the template, inside a `range` loop it's the current loop item, and so on.  In [What is, and what use cases have the dot "." in helm charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472224/what-is-and-what-use-cases-have-the-dot-in-helm-charts) I list out more cases.

And finally `$` is a variable as well.  In the context of for example a `range` loop, `$` keeps the top-level value, even if `.` changes.  `$` should *always* be the top-level Helm value.

The place where this makes a difference is in the context of a `range` loop or something else that rebinds `.`.  In that case, you need `$.Values` to refer to the top-level object.

---

As an example, let's say `values.yaml` contains

```yaml
varName: foo
someNumbers:
  - one
  - two
  - three
```

Then in this template file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    # in the top level template so these are the same
    value-is-foo: {{ .Values.varName }}
    value-is-also-foo: {{ $.Values.varName }}
data:
{{- range .Values.someNumbers }}
  # now $ is the top-level object, but . is "one", "two", "three"
  {{ . }}: one, two, or three
  {{ $.Values.varName }}-{{ . }}: foo-one, foo-two, foo-three
  {{ .Values.varName }}: |-
    an error, since the string "one" doesn't have a field or
    member "Values"
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

In Helm charts, the syntax `.Values.varName` is used to directly access a value from the `values.yaml` file. On the other hand, `$.Values.varName` is used to reference a value using a Go template expression. The dollar sign (`$`) followed by a dot (`.`) indicates the start of a template expression. This is useful when you need to perform more complex operations or transformations on the value before using it in your chart.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Kindly provide a simple example for my better understanding.